# Best internal(private) ip addressing practices for serial connections (IPv4)

Tags: best-practices, frame-relay

i have the network topology in the diagram below. i was given the Internal address block of 100.1.0.0 for assigning IP addresses.

[image: Topology Diagram]

Router 1
has a public ip address to the ISP

router 2
i assigned it the network 100.1.7.0/24 which allows enough space for the 204 hosts

router 3
i assigned it the network 100.1.8.0/26 which allows enough space for the 50 hosts

router 4
connected to r1 and frame relay.

router 6
i assigned it the 4 networks 100.1.6.0/26, 100.1.6.64/26, 100.1.6.128/64, 100.1.6.192/64 which allows enough space for the 4 * 44 hosts networks.

router 5
i assigned it the 6 networks 100.1.0.0/24, 100.1.1.0/24, 100.1.2.0/24 - 100.1.5.0/24 which allows enough space for the 6 * 210 hosts networks.

my question is what ip addresses should i assign the serial ports of r1 - r2, r1 - r3, r1 - r4, etc. 
should i use another network(100.1.9.0) or use up free addresses in lets say the 100.1.8.0 block like 100.1.8.64/30, 100.1.8.68/30, 100.1.8.72/30 ?

what is good practice in this situation as i will be summarize the addresses for smaller routing tables.

the routing protocol i will be using will be OSPF.

R1 will be implementing Nat.

thanks

Comment: 100.1.0.0 is **not** a private network address

Comment: i know but thats what we were given for the internal IP address of our assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For point-to-point links, use a maximum size of /30.  Depending on your model of router, it may support a subnet size of /31 which would be even better.  Carve these small subnets out of your unused space.  You can reserve a /24 network and use it only for p2p links, then take your smaller /30 /31 subnets from this space.